# How can I edit my quartus project to work with relative paths?

Tags: quartus

I have a project in quartus with many files containing full-path-links to other files.
I found a way to make it work on my machine with a different location, but that is the cheat way.
I would like to change all the paths to be relative, so that other engineers won't have the same problems.
What should I do?
If I change all my "C:\projects\filt..." to relative "..." will I ever get newly generated files with full paths when I continue working with it ?
And what should I do when i create a new quartus project (with nios hw and sw) to make full-path-links never appear anywhere?

For example the filt.elf file:
 `...filt_NIOSII_SW.c D:\filt\software\filt_NIOSII ...`
For example the filt_NIOSII_SW.o file:
 `... alt_alarm_list D:\filt\software\filt_NIOSII_BSP alt_llist_insert...`
For example the libhal_bsp.a file:
 `... filt_NIOSII_SW.c D:\filt\software\filt_NIOSII signed char ...`

Comment: Could you give a specific example where you have these absolute paths in your files?

Comment: edited the initial post. Here are some examples.